# TypeError and AttributeError when creating BooleanVar() object in Tkinter application

Tags: python, tkinter, typeerror, tk-toolkit, attributeerror

I want to create a BooleanVar() object, move_choice_S, which responds to the Button self.bttn15
and the function update_moves() and displays the content when the button is pressed in the textbox self.txt_box. I'm not sure how and where to instantiate the object move_choice_S, I've tried with move_choice_S = BooleanVar() to then use the command self.update_moves() but I keep getting AttributeError and TypeError with the errormessage that there is no instance called move_choice_S. I've also tried to import Tkinter as tk and move_choice_S = tk.BooleanVar() but I keep getting AttributeError:Application instance has no attribute 'move_choice_S'. How should I instantiate the object self.move_choice_S?

```
class Application(Frame):


    def __init__(self, master):
        """ init the frame """
        Frame.__init__(self) 
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):

       self.bttn15 = Button(self, text = "OK", variable = self.move_choice_S, command =  self.update_moves)
        self.bttn15.grid(row = 14, column = 4, sticky = W)

      # message
        self.box_txt = Text(self, width = 65, height = 25, wrap = WORD)
        self.box_txt.grid(row = 15, column = 0, columnspan = 5, sticky = W)


   def update_moves(self):

        moves = ""
        if self.move_choice_S.get():
            moves = "S"

        self.box_txt.insert(0.0, END) 


        self.box_txt.insert(0.0, moves) 


# Main
root = tk.Tk()

move_choice_S = tk.BooleanVar()
move_choice_S.set(True)
move_choice_S.get()


root.title("Maltparser1.0_demo")

root.geometry("900x700")

app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: in this code, you are getting "AttributeError:Application instance has no attribute 'move_choice_S'" because move_choice_S created in main not in class Application so you don't need "self" to 'work' this code. Since you are setting your variable True as soon as running code, it will always insert S after you press the button.

Comment: and what are your versions of tkinter, python?

Comment: I'm using Python 2.6.6, I keep getting the same error about the option variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your code a bit. Now it is running without error but since you are setting your `move_choice_S` to `True`, it is writing to `text` only `S` on each button press.

**EDIT**: I updated `move_choice_S` parts. Since you defined `move_choice_S` in global scope,  you don't need use `self.` to use/reach it. You can use it by `move_choice_S` or as @FabienAndre said, you can define it in `__init__`.

`-option sticky` needs its argument as string. So I changed those.

`insert` needs at least two arguments. First is index and the second is what is going to be inserted.

I imported using `import xxx` form, so I changed all `tkinter` items according to that but it's just a habit. You don't have to use this `import` form.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        """ init the frame """
        tk.Frame.__init__(self) 
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.bttn15 = tk.Button(self, text = "OK", command = self.update_moves)
        self.bttn15.grid(row = 14, column = 4, sticky = "W")

        # message
        self.box_txt = tk.Text(self, width = 65, height = 25, wrap = "word")
        self.box_txt.grid(row = 15, column = 0, columnspan = 5, sticky = "W")

    def update_moves(self):

        moves = ""
        if move_choice_S.get():
            moves = "S"

        self.box_txt.insert(0.0, moves + "\n") 

# Main
root = tk.Tk()

move_choice_S = tk.BooleanVar()
move_choice_S.set(True)
move_choice_S.get()


root.title("Maltparser1.0_demo")

root.geometry("900x700")

app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your answer would be better if you described what you changed. As it is now, a reader is forced to do a line-by-line comparison to see what you did.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating `move_choice_S` variable in the global namespace. It can be reached from anywhere in your program using the raw name `move_choice_S`.

To fix your problem, you can either:

- access it without `self` in `update_moves`,
- define it in the `Application` constructor, ie:

  ```
  class Application(Frame):
      def __init__(self, master):
          (...)
          self.move_choice_S = BooleanVar()
  ```

You might read [this book chapter](http://beastie.cs.ua.edu/cs150/book/index_13.html) for in-depth explanation on scope in Python.